# Integrating Twitter API into iPhone app gives errors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, twitter

In my iPhone app there is a requirement for Twitter API integration.

Here the problem comes when I integrate the Twitter+ OAuth SDK into my app. It gives errors as shown below in the screen shot.

I have added the xml2.dylib library to my app but still it gives some errors.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer.

I am posting it here because I don't want to put answer to my own question to earn reputation :). I made a silly mistake.

I didn't add the **"Header Search Paths**" in project settings as `"\usr\include\xml2"`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the header file(s) which is importing "xmlversion.h", "tree.h", "xmlIO.h" from your application target.
In one of my project, I am using **MGTwitterEngine** libray. I was facing the same problem while inegrating the library with my application. Then I read following link which helped me to solve the problem
http://aralbalkan.com/3133

Comment: Thanks for your help. This issue is solved. I have already edited my Question and Added the Answer there. :)